# Full-screen background images in website looks blurry

Tags: css

i am currently facing full screen images blurry issue, no matter what size i changed for my background image (tried 1800px, 1600px), it came out same blurry issue. Been searching google but still cant find result. hope someone can solve. thx

For your info, i'm using "save for web" in photoshop. My web is (http://maxgohblog.blogspot.com/)

Comment: you are resizing your image too almost twice it's saved dimensions. Save the file from photo shop at the resolution that you are going to use it (i.e 1800px x1600px)

Comment: hi, i have just resized again direct from original file to 1800. but too bad, it is still blurred.

Comment: ok its finally ok after i upload the photo from tinypic. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't the images to appear in better quality you have to take a higher resolution. Basicly your image was blewn up from 800px width to 1400px, if you inspect it in your Developer Tools. It's lika a bowl of 800 beans but you need 1400 of them to be full.

Comment: hi, my original file is 4200px and i was resized to 1800 and 1600 but no matter what sizes, it will get blur once i put it as background image. here is the 1600px  http://i135.photobucket.com/albums/q140/maxgoh/max-2_zpsma80s9yj.jpg~original thank you

Comment: ok its finally ok after i upload the photo from tinypic. thank you